# Work Hours Related Badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, fun

So, myself and a colleague were discussing at work just now that we really need a project in our time recording software to mark down our Trilogy site time as we tend to camp there while tests are running, etc.

Which got us thinking...

Should there be a 'Work Hours' related badges (bronze, silver, gold)? I'm sure there would be a few people who qualify for this already.  :)

Comment: What are the criteria for awarding this badge? Having a certain percentage of posts made during "working hours"?

Comment: That sounds like an applicable criteria

Comment: Obviously some people haven't seen the tongue in cheek request...

Comment: Oh, they did, Dan, they are just cheeking you. You know, it's not Friday...

Comment: Congratulations for the first badge I **really** wouldn't want associated with me. (Even if it somewhat accurate.)

Comment: It would be interesting to know, of the down voters, what percentage would of achieved at least 1 of the badges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be encouraging no working in favor of spending time on SO... how will potential employers see people that have this gold badge?

Comment: "So awesome they can spend half their time on S* and *still* outperform their colleagues".

Comment: That's a possibility...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how this would work.  There are people working around the clock all over the world. How do you differentiate if everything is based on UTC time? This is a globally used website and they do not store time zone information. On top of that, not everyone works standard hours.

Just kind of seems like more noise then feature/benefit/reward. Maybe you can prove me wrong on how this could work well?

Comment: Location field in profile? Although, yes, Garbage in and Garbage out. It isn't like a few other badges don't get gamed though...

Comment: Just count it all as work time.... ;)

Comment: It feels like that sometimes :)